# Vtiger : How we have to manage Email thread on Lead Module?

Tags: vtiger, vtigercrm

We are sending email to customer from Lead module and email sent to customer successfully from Vtiger. also we have integrate Mail Manager
in Vtiger.

[image]

i can also see that email in Sent box.

[image]

now, When Customer will give reply for that mail which i have sent from Lead module that will automatically appear in Lead Module Email Tab. right now i am getting am reply in Mail Box but i need log email in Lead section with particular customer replay.

Please help me if anyone solution..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's by default functionality which is provided by Vtiger CRM.

We have configure Mail Scanner and select folder which we have to scan.

also, we have add condition or rule for this what we have to do if we can get result while scanning.

Please check status for `MailScanner` in `vtiger_cron_task` table.  it must be 1.

also we have to set `vtigercron.php` in cronjob.

you can also run `vtigercron.php` in console on server with below command

```
php vtigercron.php
```

After success full scan you can get below message

[image]

Please Let me know if you have any question.